# scponly worked but didn't chroot the home folder, the user can still browse the entire server

Tags: chroot, scp

So I followed the "Chroot and Debian" tutorial in http://sublimation.org/scponly/wiki/index.php/FAQ

Then when I log into user "upload" via ssh I have no access to the command line (this is what I wanted).

But then when I SFTP into the upload user I can still see all the root files (/), it didn't chroot me to just /home/upload whats going on?

….

I added this to the end of my /etc/ssh/sshd_config file, then done a restart

```
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp

UsePAM yes

Match User upload
    ChrootDirectory /home/upload
    AllowTCPForwarding no
    X11Forwarding no
    ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

Then when I log into sftp I can only see my upload folder (this is what I want), but now scp doesn't work :P

SCP will accept my password then:

```
debug1: Next authentication method: password
upload@10.10.10.2's password: 
debug1: Authentication succeeded (password).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_NZ.UTF-8
debug1: Sending command: scp -v -t /test
```

It will hang on that last debug message.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Note, running Debian Lenny

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are **not** using `scponly` here. You have restricted the user `upload` to using SFTP, so you can't use `scp` on that account since `scp` relies on an interactive shell or at least a shell which supports certain commands (like `scponly` or `rssh`).

Use `sftp` or another SFTP client (e. g. `lftp`) to access that account or remove the `ForceCommand` and `ChrootDirectory` directives from your sshd_config.

Comment: I don't want to use sftp as I don't need human interaction, I just need it for a script to transfer a file or two to the server now and then. From what I'v read scp is the idea tool for that.  Oh and when I  take out the chroot made by sshd I get full access to all my directories, Ill try compile scponly as suggested below but I fear it wont help.

Comment: SFTP is just a protocol. Clients like `lftp` also support non-interactive modes. And even `sftp` (OpenSSH's SFTP client) supports batch mode (see parameter `-b`).

Comment: Yeah I know, but I still like scp, as it's supposed to be somewhat faster at copying.

Comment: I really doubt that `scp` is faster than `sftp`. Nevertheless, I've already described in the last paragraph of my answer what you have to do to make `scp` work again.

Comment: Yeah, scponly works fine via apt-get install on my test server, but didn't on the live one… So I might re-install the live one and see how it goes from there.

Answer (score 1):

scponly supports chroot natively.  There are compile-time options to enable it, particularly `--enable-chrooted-binary`.  scponly will need the SUID bit to enable chroot.

If already compiled, you will have the binary file `scponlyc` available on your filesystem.

There are also limitations as to the usefulness of chroot as a security solution.

- [Some people hate chroot](https://serverfault.com/questions/97091/when-is-it-appropriate-prudent-to-use-chroot)
- [Additional details on scponly](http://sublimation.org/scponly/wiki/index.php/Install#Decide_If_You_Want_To_Use_The_chroot.28.29_Functionality)

Comment: So I have to compile scponly with chroot?
I can't enable it from an apt-get install?

I choose yes when this message came up when installing scponly via apt-get: http://img.skitch.com/20100302-s1xjtmmdsgitcgi76y7yqu4gr.png

Comment: Sounds/looks like that will cover you, Mint.